# Fix VS Mobile Center Error: Publish build artifacts failed with error: Not found PathtoPublish

Tags: visual-studio-app-center, mobile-center

When starting a build in Visual Studio App Center I am getting this error in the build logs.  How do I fix this?

```
    ==============================================================================
    ##[error]Publish build artifacts failed with error: Not found PathtoPublish: /Users/ci/agent/vstsagent/_work/1/a/symbols
    ##[section]Finishing: Publish symbols
    ##[section]Starting: Create distribution
    ==============================================================================
    Task         : Mobile Center Upload
    Description  : Upload mobile app packages to Visual Studio Mobile Center
    Version      : 0.115.1
    Author       : Microsoft Corporation
    Help         : Upload mobile app packages to Visual Studio Mobile Center
    ==============================================================================
    ##[warning]Cannot find any file based on /Users/ci/agent/vstsagent/_work/1/a/symbols.
    ##[error]TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of null
    ##[section]Finishing: Create distribution
    ##[section]Starting: Post Job Cleanup
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**In order to fix this issue you can try the following:**

1. Open your project.
2. Go to Build Settings.
3. For Debug Information Format select "DWARF with dSYM File".
4. Commit code and push to repo.
5. Run build again.

[image: Setup Gif]